# The easiest way to connect 2 PC into one local network?

Tags: windows-7, home-networking

What is the best way to share data between two PC inside 192.169.1.x ? (for example, to use printer or to share files). Are there specific settings in router admin pane?

These two PCs have classic IPs 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.101 with gate 192.168.1.1, but I can't even to ping one from another..

Comment: What operating system is running on each machine?

Comment: I'm sorry..we have Win7 on both

Comment: We need to know what OS your systems are running on, what sort of router you're using to connect, whether or not the systems are using software firewalls, and how (Wi-Fi/LAN) they are connected.  If both are connected via LAN, you probably don't need to configure the router.  You may need to setup services and firewall options on the hosts, though.  If connected via Wi-Fi, there may be additional settings you do need to tweak on the router.  Please edit all of the requested details into your question post.

Comment: If you have the Windows Firewall on, to enable ping on Windows 7:            
Control Panel --> System and security --> Windows Firewall --> Advanced settings --> Inbound rules --> New rule --> custom rule

in Protocol and ports: Protocol: ICMPv4 
on the same panel go to customize, choose "Specific ICMP types", check the box "echo request". Also - what are you using for a router/switch/etc.

Answer (score 2):

Once you can start pinging, since you both use Windows 7, set up a [homegroup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/homegroup-from-start-to-finish). It's dead simple and works.